# How to get number of word wrap breaks in richtextboxusing c#?

Tags: word-wrap

I am working with the rich text box where i need to in crease its size whenever i get the word wrap....as of now i m just counting the number of character and if character goes above the limit i m just changing the height of the rich text box.... I know this is not proper way so i m searching for answer where i can get the word wrap count. So i can increase the height that many times....Please Help me.....

Thanks in advance.....

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you check the [VerticalScrollBarVisibility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.textboxbase.verticalscrollbarvisibility.aspx) property to determine whether there is a scroll bar - and increase the height if there is?